# Text file into 2D string

Tags: c, string, file, multidimensional-array, text-files

Please can you help me with my code? I want to convert my text file into 2D string line by line. I tried some conditions but it didn't work.

---

m - number of lines

n - number of columns

---

*This is my function:*

```
int convert_text_file_into_2Dstring(int m, int n)
{   
    int i, j;
    int **string= (char **)malloc(m * sizeof(char *));
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
         string[i] = (char *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        for(j=0; j< m){
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is nothing like a 2D string. I understand what you want but you shall correct your wording (also the identifier of the function).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a nice C99 Feature:

```
int convert_text_file_into_2Dstring(int m, int n)
{
    int i, j;
    int string[m][n];
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j< m ; j++)
        {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

So you don't need to malloc and have to free later on.

If you can't use that feature, because the compiler won't support it, you should free your allocated memory:

```
int i, j;
int **string= (int **)malloc(m * sizeof(char *));

for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    string[i] = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));

for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    for(j=0; j< m ; j++)
    {
        //...
    }
}

for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    free(string[i]);

free(string);
```

now you could set into the inner loop something like this:

```
string[j][i] = text[i];
```

A bit more convenient could be using strcpy:

```
int convert_text_file_into_2Dstring(int m, int n)
{
    int i, j;
    int string[m][n];
    for(j=0; j< m ; j++)
    {
       strncpy(string[j],text,n);
    }
}
```